# Are evals concurrently safe across targets?

Tags: makefile, eval

I'm wondering if there are any potential race conditions when using evals across targets.   So for example, if I have:

```
all1:
    $(eval X:=1)
    $(eval Y:=1)
    @echo "[$@] X: $(X), Y: $(Y)"

all2:
    $(eval Y:=2);
    $(eval X:=2);
    @echo "[$@] X: $(X), Y: $(Y)"
```

and then ran

```
 make all all2 -j
```

Are `X` and `Y` guaranteed to be the same values for the same target, or can one instance of the target expansion potentially scribble on the other as it's expanding?

(Background -- I'm debugging an inconsistent make bug on some makefiles which use evals to set some common variables across many targets, and I'm wondering if this could be a contributing factor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make -j` runs each job in a separate process. Variable changes don't transfer between make processes.

Comment: So this raises another question -- if I have `all2 : all1; echo $(X)` and `all1: ;$(eval X:=Y)`, then if `all2` happens to get invoked on another process, then `X` may not be set for `all2`?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It seems majorly suspect to be setting variables inside target rules. Bad idea, I'd avoid it entirely.